# SaveFileDialog под текущей датой.

Tags: c#

Сохранить файл под текущей датой

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "Текстовый документ (*.txt)|*.txt|Все файлы (*.*)|*.*";

        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");
            streamWriter.WriteLine(textBox5.Text);
            streamWriter.WriteLine(textBox10.Text);
            streamWriter.WriteLine(textBox15.Text);
            streamWriter.WriteLine(textBox20.Text);
            streamWriter.WriteLine(textBox25.Text);
            streamWriter.WriteLine(textBox30.Text);

            streamWriter.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто подставь дату в качестве дефаултного имени файла в диалог перед его открытием.

Или используй диалог выбора папки, а не файла.

Comment: Пробовал ничего не получается, ставил и перед и после... результат пустая форма сохранения...(

Comment: Я так понимаю ошибка в этой строке "StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");"

Comment: Все спасибо. Розобрался

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog.Filter = "Текстовый документ (*.txt)|*.txt|Все файлы (*.*)|*.*";
     saveFileDialog.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");
    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.FileName);
        streamWriter.WriteLine(textBox5.Text);
        streamWriter.WriteLine(textBox10.Text);
        streamWriter.WriteLine(textBox15.Text);
        streamWriter.WriteLine(textBox20.Text);
        streamWriter.WriteLine(textBox25.Text);
        streamWriter.WriteLine(textBox30.Text);

        streamWriter.Close();
    }
```